# need to use update the alternate rows of the data getting by the below query. Not able to use widows function in update statement ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with below query: I want to update every alternate row of a table given some conditions, which includes multiple tables I am not able to use windows function under update how can I modify this query to work

```
UPDATE loanacct 
    SET 
        collection_officer_no = 
        (
                CASE
                    WHEN
                        ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY acctrefno)  %2 = 0 
                    THEN 
                        4
                    ELSE
                        7
                    END
        )

WHERE acctrefno in 
    (
    SELECT 
    [acctrefno]
FROM 
    [NLS].[dbo].[loanacct] L
    INNER JOIN nlsusers U ON U.userno = L.collection_officer_no
WHERE
    U.username like 'house' AND 
    L.loan_group_no in ( '2', '4', '5') AND`enter code here`
    L.days_past_due > 25 AND  
    status_code_no = 0)
```

Comment: MS SQL SERVER (my bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a updatable CTE. This is pseudo-SQL, but should get you on the right path:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {YourColumns},
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (/* PARTITION BY ??? */ ORDER BY {Column} AS RN
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ...
    )
UPDATE CTE
SET ...
WHERE RN % 2 = 0;
```